# Read property file and Insert xml tag using shell script

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I Have a property file as below ,

```
Name=sample
TagName=Test1
TagType=P

Name=sample1
TagName=Test2
TagType=Y
```

I have a xml file as below ,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
  </root>
```

Need to append as below ,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <sub>
      <TagName>Test1</TagName>
      <TagType>P</TagType>
    </sub>
    <sub>
      <TagName>Test2</TagName>
     <TagType>Y</TagType>
    </sub>
  </root>
```

Can any one help me to insert in xml file using sed or awk command in shell script ...

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: If that's really all your xml file contains then what's the point of having it when you need to generate all of the other xml constructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bash` and `xmlstarlet`. I removed the space before `<?xml` in your xml file.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="file.xml"
prop="property.txt"

while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
  [[ "$key" == "Name" ]]    && xmlstarlet edit -L --subnode '//root'             --type elem -n "sub" "$file"
  [[ "$key" == "TagName" ]] && xmlstarlet edit -L --subnode '//root/sub[last()]' --type elem -n "TagName" --value "$value" "$file"
  [[ "$key" == "TagType" ]] && xmlstarlet edit -L --subnode '//root/sub[last()]' --type elem -n "TagType" --value "$value" "$file"
done < "$prop"
```

Output to file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <sub>
    <TagName>Test1</TagName>
    <TagType>P</TagType>
  </sub>
  <sub>
    <TagName>Test2</TagName>
    <TagType>Y</TagType>
  </sub>
</root>
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit` for a quick syntax overview.